# Fill Access table from SQL, autogenerate ID Field in Access

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access

I create some data from SQL table, and I need to insert it in Access table.

Those tables are pretty much identical. My export works normally. The ptroblem that I have is IDField in the access. So far I send the ID from the SQL server, and it takes them.

I do not want to do that, I want Access to create it on its own.

This is the statement that I send to Access:

```
commandText = "INSERT INTO tbl_mytable VALUES (" + "'" + myID + "'" + ",'value one','value two',NULL,'kilogram','111',NULL,'30.10.2015 00:00:00','0','1')";
```

And it works.

How can I modify it, to send a null or something, and let the access figure out the ID.

tbl_mytable in SQL has autoincremnt ID field named myID. Access table also has the same field and it is set to autoincrement as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the target fields, then you can omit the ID column.

See second example in [INSERT INTO Statement (Microsoft Access SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208861%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your SQL, where you specify, which columns in acces should be filled. Just skip to define the autoincrement-ID-field. It will be set automatically.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_mytable (column1,column2,column3)
VALUES ('value one','value two', ,'value three');
```

Here is a good explanation
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp